# Make Transparent background of android icons in eclipse

Tags: android, user-interface, icons, imageview, transparent

How to make android icons with transparent background using eclipse.I know that we can make icons by eclipse->new->other->android icon set but how to make them with transparent background?Any help please.

Comment: You mean icons used to launch the app? AFAIK android takes "normal" images and applies the glow and rounded rect bounds on each image itself. For more information check out the android documentation.

Comment: @banzai86 Nope, that doesn't happen. It displays just as you save it, no additional processing goes on.

Comment: @kcoppock ah sry, you are right, mixed it up with Apple's approch. So you will have to create your transparent images all on your own using Photoshop or Gimp for example

Comment: @user1437033 for guidance on "Do's and Don'ts" see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse isn't an image editing program. If it has some basic functionality built in for that, I wouldn't recommend using it for design. If you have Photoshop, or can download GIMP, use those instead for icon design.

Also, be sure to save them as PNG and not JPG, as JPG does not support transparency.

Comment: But then should i make them transparent for all layouts(hdpi,ldpi,mdpi etc.)?

Comment: That's up to you. That's the 'design' part. ;) If it's transparent for one layout, there's certainly no reason that I can think of not to do the same for other layouts.

Answer (score 6):

If your icon is transparent background and you would like to keep it while creating a new icon using Android Eclipse, clicking Shape None will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Once you actually create your image, you can set the background to transparent using

```
@android:color/transparent
```